# Finding the representative matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have f: $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x,x,z)$, with the representative matrix $A$, but this is from the canonical base to the canonical basis $B$.

I want to find the representative matrix of this function $A'$, but going from basis $B' = ((1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1))$ to $B'$

I know that the change of matrix basis is

$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Thus, $M*[x]_{B'} = [x]_{B}$ and $M*[f(x)]_{B'} = [f(x)]_{B} \implies [f(x)]_{B'} = M^{-1}AM[x]_{B'}$. Thus, $A' = M^{-1}AM$.

However, this seems like rather tedious work, and my professor seems to solve these really quick. Is there a faster way of doing this?

When we want the representative matrix of a transformation going from the *canonical basis* to an arbitrary basis, he simply finds it by finding the matrix

\begin{pmatrix} f(e_1) ... f(e_n) \\  \end{pmatrix}

where $e_1, ... , e_n$ is the basis, but the terms are in the arbitary basis. I don't understand how this works, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you have a linear transformation $f:(E,\mathcal{B}) \rightarrow (E,\mathcal{B})$ which is represented by the matrix A. We know that the columns of the matrix A are  $f(e_1),f(e_2),f(e_3)$. If $\mathcal{B'} = (e_1^{'}e_2^{'}e_3^{'})$ then you have to calculate $f(e_i^{'})$ and express the result that we will note $g(e_i^{'})$ in the new basis $\mathcal{B'}$. Then $g: (E,\mathcal{B'}) \rightarrow (E,\mathcal{B'})$ is the same linear transformation but in the basis $\mathcal{B'}$ and finally: $A' =(g(e_1^{'}),g(e_2^{'}),g(e_3^{'}))$

Comment: @Gatgat Thanks a bunch for the answer; this is what I was looking for. So, to get, for example, $g(e_1^{'})$, we find $f(e_1) = f((1,0,0)) = (1,1,0)$. Then, we multiply that by the inverse of the change-of-basis vector by $(1,1,0)$ and this gives us the first column of our $A'$?

Comment: (1,1,0) is directly the second vector of the new basis so no need to multiply by a vector. It means that in the new basis, the first column of A' is (0,1,0). Do the same with the other vectors, it should be easy to express them by using the three vectors of this new basis too. Here the columns shoud be (0,1,0),(0,1,0) and (0,0,1) if I didn't make any mistake.

Comment: @Gatgat Everything you say makes sense and falls in line with what I thought I understood. However, the right answer is supposedly: 
$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. What the hell is going on? This is so frustrating.

Comment: @Gatgat Forgive me, there was actually two ways of interpreting the function that I gave. I could have chosen (x,y,z) -> (x,x,z) or (x,y,z) -> (y,y,z). The solution in the book is for the latter function. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B'}$ be two basis of $E$. And $Mat(\mathcal{B},u)$ the matrix of u in the basis B.
If $P_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B'}}$ is the change of basis matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B'}$ then we have:

$$Mat(\mathcal{B'},u) = P_{\mathcal{B'},\mathcal{B}}Mat(\mathcal{B},u)P_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B'}} = P_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B'}}^{-1}Mat(\mathcal{B},u)P_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B'}}$$

An efficient way to visualize it is to draw the following scheme:

$$(E,\mathcal{B'}) \overset{Id_E: P_{\mathcal{B'},\mathcal{B}}}{\rightarrow} (E,\mathcal{B}) \overset{u:Mat(\mathcal{B},u)}{\rightarrow} (E,\mathcal{B})\overset{Id_E:P_{\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B'}}}{\rightarrow} (E,\mathcal{B'})$$

You just have to multiply these matrix in this order to obtain the one you want. Why this scheme? First you take a vector expressed in the basis $\mathcal{B'}$ that you transform to express it in $\mathcal{B}$, then you compose with $u$, and you transform the new vector back in $\mathcal{B'}$ from $\mathcal{B}$. I wrote $Id_E$ above some arrows because it means it's still the same vector, I just write it in an other basis.

Edit: it seems I have misunderstood what you asked for, sorry. I'll try to write an other answer.